# How to enable shortcuts (copy-paste) inside chrooted java app?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, chroot, chroot-jail

I instaled java-based app Lotus Notes inside ubuntu 12 chroot on debian host systems.
I run it with enabled

```
xhost+
```

on based system

How to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts inside Lotus Notes.

The copy-paste work with context menu inside Lotus Notes

My way of installing Lotus Notes inside chroot

```
    sudo su
    apt-get install debootstrap
    mkdir /chroots && cd /chroots
    debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 precise /chroots/ubuntu http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu
    mount proc /chroots/ubuntu/proc -t proc
    mount sysfs /chroots/ubuntu/sys -t sysfs
    chroot /chroots/ubuntu
    apt-get install aptitude
    apt-get install language-pack-ru language-pack-en
    ## deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse

   apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch

apt-get install gdb unzip bash grep sed
apt-get install libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonoboui2-0  libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0  libjpeg62 liborbit2  libpam0g libpopt0 libxkbfile1
apt-get install  libgnomeprint2.2-0:i386 libgnomeprintui2.2-0:i386 libbonobo2-0:i386 libbonoboui2-0:i386 libgconf2-4:i386 libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386 libgnomevfs2-bin:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libpam0g:i386 libxkbfile1:i386 ttf-xfree86-nonfree t1-xfree86-nonfree -y
apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386 xterm
  dpkg --install ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb 
adduser lotus
su lotus
/opt/ibm/notes/notes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing of xorg inside chroot helps me